# Как заполнить textarea информацией из javascript переменнной

Tags: javascript

Есть такая необходимость передать переменную в `textarea` по нажатию кнопки.

Вводные данные:

```
<script>
  var insta = "<?php echo $instapost; ?>";
  function addinsta() {
    document.getElementById("txtpost").innerHTML = insta;
  }
</script>
```

Переменная `insta` успешно получает многострочный текст из php-переменной `$instapost`.Далее необходимо, по нажатию `button` заполнить `<textarea>` полученной переменной.

*Собственно, что имеем:*

```
<button id="instabutton" onclick="addinsta()">Generate Post</button><br />
<textarea id="txtpost" name="txtpost"></textarea>
```

Как только не пробовал:  `document.getElementById("txtpost").value = insta` - тоже не работает.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что `document.getElementById("txtpost").value = insta` не работает?

Comment: "многострочный текст" - и как это выглядит в браузере? `var insta = ` - чему равно?

Comment: не работает document.getElementById("txtpost").value = insta потому, что переменная не помещается в <textarea>.

var insta = несколько строк текста. php-переменная подтягивается из внешнего файла через include, потом подменяются некоторые данные:  $instapost = str_replace ($oldvars, $newvars, $instapost) где $oldvars и $newvars - массивы данных. ну и получаем var insta = <?php echo $instapost; ?>

Comment: как это выглядит в браузере? `var insta =` - чему равно?

Comment: ну собственно то, с чем сейчас борюсь расположено по адресу http://kmdb.com.ua/addons/mailer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошим простым решением будет сделать так:

```
<script>
  var insta = <?php echo json_encode($instapost); ?>;

  function addinsta() {
    document.getElementById("txtpost").value = insta;
  }
</script>
```

Кстати, слеш экранируется, так что проблемы со `</script>` в строке [не возникнет](https://ideone.com/6e9bY9).

Comment: кстати, тоже отличный вариант.
Спасибо!

Comment: @Creator, только небольшая поправка - всё-таки `value`, а не `innerHTML`.

Comment: а в чем кардинальное отличие?

Comment: @Creator, идейно правильнее, что у всех контролов есть value, а innerHTML - это разметка у всяких элементов. В Хроме с textarea работает одинаково (c input'ом - уже нет), но я не уверен в кроссбраузерности присваивания innerHTML.

Comment: в целом понятно. кроссбраузерность проверю уже завтра!
Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте "\" в конце каждой строки:

```js
var insta = "Какое то имя\n\
Модель открытой базы данных украинских детей-моделей 'Kids Models'\n\
 лет. , Украина\n\
\n\
\n\
Опыт работы:  года\n\
\n\
\n\
Награды: \n\
\n\
Анкету модели, а так же полный каталог моделей можно найти на портале Kids Models. Ссылка в профиле.\n\
\n\
#kmdb, #kidsmodels, #kidsmodelsua, #backstage, #model, #topmodel, #photomodel, #kidmodel, #fashion, #fashionkids, #casting, #tfp, #кастинг, #модель, #детимодели, #мальчикимодели, #детскаямода, #фотосессия";

function addinsta() {
  document.getElementById("txtpost").innerHTML = insta;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="instabutton" style="width: 270px;" onclick="addinsta()">Generate Instagram Post</button><br />
<div id="extra">
<textarea id="txtpost" name="txtpost"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: надо понимать в переменной? сейчас попробую!

Comment: добавил. при нажатии на кнопку "Generate Instagram Post" - переменная добавляется в textarea, но не сохраняется там. сразу после нажатия мигнуло и пропало. ((

Comment: @Creator это оно Вам подмигивает: `<button type="button" ...`

Comment: нууу. прошу прощения, не смог подобрать правильное определение тому, что происходит при нажатии кнопки.

Comment: исправил! уже работает! благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @Creator при нажатии происходилa отправка формы и перезагрузка страницы

Comment: Только ```\n\```, наверное, чтоб переводы строк сохранились.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, точно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась следующей конструкцией:

```
<script>
  var insta = `<?php echo $instapost; ?>`;
  function addinsta() {
    document.getElementById("txtpost").innerHTML = insta;
  };
</script>
```

Что бы не расставлять "\" в конце каждой строки - php-переменную обрамил в обратные кавычки ``, согласно стандарту ES-2015 (в них разрешен перевод строк). Все заработало!

Comment: А если в тексте окажется обратная кавычка или `${`? А ещё ES2015 не работае в IE.

Comment: те переменные, которые я определяю не будут содержать обратные кавычки. ну а поддержка IE мне точно не нужна, так как то, что я делаю - я делаю фактически только для себя, ну а я работаю за маком, где априори нет IE.

Comment: Но ведь это не мешает сделать правильно?)

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда лучше var insta = <?php echo json_encode($instapost); ?>;

Comment: Ага, в json'е не будет потенциальных injection'ов.