# Данные из textarea приходят без учета переноса строки(html, js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Есть форма с textarea, пользователь вводит туда текст, которые потом идет в БД (CouchDB), а оттуда уже обратно на страницу. Проблема в том, что текст приходит в одну строку, т.е. без учета переноса строки. Как сделать так чтобы перенос сохранялся. Проект делаю на js и nodejs.

Textarea находиться в index.ejs

Comment: При чем здесь регистр?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732232

Comment: Эта ссылка мало чем помогла, у меня textarea находится в index.ejs и document.getElementById() приводит к ошибке

Comment: "текст приходит в одну строку" - куда текст приходит без переносов?

Comment: Да, приходит без переносов, но в БД храниться как "text": "sdsd\r\nNew string\r\nNew string again"

Comment: Точнее сказать приходит обратно в index.ejs из БД

Comment: что, и даже "\r\n" там нет?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73614/discussion-between-paul-pak-and-igor).

Answer (score 2):

Перенос сохраняется, только он приходит в виде `\n`
Чтобы отобразить попробуйте воспользоваться этим
`'your\ntext\nfrom\nbd'.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1<br>$2')`

Comment: Сделал. Помогло, но теперь текст выводиться как "New string<br> New string<br> New string again", т.е. прямо с тегами, и не заменяется переносами. Как это исправить, подскажите, я совсем чайник)

Comment: А в исходном коде вообще отмечено 1. Молоко&lt;br&gt;
2.Хлеб

Comment: В исходном коде тэги экранируются. А куда Вы текст выводите? Я имел ввиду вывод непосредственно на html страницу. Как я понял у Вас шаблонизатор, тогда непосредственно в нем сделайте данный фильтр и применяйте его.